# fullPage.js utilizing .active and .fp-viewing-firstpage-X classes

Tags: javascript, css, fullpage.js

I have a webpage that utilizes [fullPage.JS](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/).  There is a firstPage section with 5 horizontal slides that is navigated to with a header menu via data-menuanchor. Additionally there is a secondPage section with 3 horizontal slides that is navigated with a footer menu, also via data-menuanchor.

I would like for each li menu item to change color when it's corresponding section is navigated to. Right now I am accomplishing MOST of this by using the :focus CSS selector.  However this only works when a menu item is clicked.  I also need the highlights to change when navigation is done via touchscrolling, keyscrolling, etc.

Initially I thought I could accomplish this by using the "active" class as it is passed to the menu, but I quickly realized that, because of the structure of my page, the "active" class is simultaneously passed to every li in the menu....either all five items in my header menu or all 3 items in my footer menu.

After concluding that I would not be able to use the "active" class to differentiate as needed, I began looking at the "fp-viewing-firstpage-X" class that is given to the body as each section and slide is navigated to...

However, I am not having luck with either approach I've come up with.

First I tried to do it all with CSS with something like this:

```
.fp-viewing-firstpage-1 .item {
color:white;
}
```

After not having success with that I tried using this javascript in the onLoad, onLeave, afterRender callbacks, etc...:

```
if ( $('body').hasClass('fp-viewing-firstpage-1') ) {
    $('.item').addClass('white');
    }
```

So far neither approach has accomplished my goal of changing the color of whichever menu item's corresponding section is navigate to, regardless of HOW is is navigated to.

Your assistance is appreciated!

Comment: Add a reproduction of your issue in jsfiddle or codepen. You'll get more answers.

Comment: Alvaro, I was able to solve the problem with the just CSS option. Thanks for your reply and thanks for the awesome plugin!